# I need assistence with android app life cycle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lifecycle

I've created this simple example to illustrate what i am trying to accomplish.

This is my first layout:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class LifeCycleActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private RadioButton rbR, rbG, rbB;
private RadioGroup rg;
private Button next;
int color=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    rbR = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rbB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rbG = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final Intent it = new Intent(this, next.class);
    final Bundle b = new Bundle();

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            b.putInt("color", color);
            it.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
}

public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (checkedId==rbR.getId()) color=1;
    if (checkedId==rbB.getId()) color=2;
    if (checkedId==rbG.getId()) color=3;
}
```

}

This is the second layout:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class next extends Activity {

private LinearLayout ll;
private ImageView im;
private TextView tv;
private Button save;
private Bundle extras;
private int color=0;
private String selColor="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainll);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    im = new ImageView(this);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    save = new Button(this);
    save.setText("save");

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    color = extras.getInt("color");

    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    ll.addView(im);

    if (color == 1) selColor = "RED";
    if (color == 2) selColor = "BLUE";
    if (color == 3) selColor = "GREEN";
    tv.setText(selColor);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    ll.addView(tv);
    ll.addView(save);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // here i want to save and exit
            // so i can call onPause(), then finish()
            // do not know how exactly since i have to follow some goals 
            // that i need for this example
        }
    });
}
```

}

I also have main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="red" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blue" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="green" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AND next.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, based on color selection in first layout I dynamically build the second layout.

This is what I want to do, help me please (add code if possible):

1. on the second layout if I press save, I want to save app state (whatever I built on that page) and exit.
2. If I add one more button to create other dynamic objects on that layout (EditText with name, or another layout with different objects) than if user saves, he/she will also save new objects (This part can be done later)
3. if user saved that page once then i want him to be able to get the same app state that he/she was in before exiting (of course if he/she selects the same radio button).
4. If he/she selects another button, i do not need to show that previous state, since the selection is different.

Comment: use SQLite database to store the states, thats always the safest option. you can always update the database by calling onPause() and onStop() method. :)

Comment: I can save everything with sharedpreferencea too, but i cannot properly imlement onPause and onStart functions to get the results i want. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick with **`sharedpreferences`** did for me. I was finally able to same and retrieve my data `onPause` and `onStart`. Even though this worked fine, I appreciate the answer of Kevin_Dingo which is  defiantly more professional way to go.